# Splunk use time from first search of Join command in second search

Tags: join, splunk, splunk-query

I'm trying to calculate the avarage time users take to fill out one of our forms. I'm using their Ip address to identify the user. Sometimes users only retrieve the form once before filling it out, but they might also do it multiple times, even after submitting it. I want to use the last retrieval time BEFORE the time the form was submitted to get a best estimate of the fill out time. I can't seem to use the time of the first search as the time for the second search

I've tried the following:

```
index=sys GET form
| rex "(?<ipAdd>.*), \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}, \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}" 
| stats latest(_time) as submitTime by ipAdd
| join ipAdd
        [search index=sys GET form
    | rex "(?<ipAdd>.*), \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}, \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}"
    | stats latest(submitTime) as retrieveTime by ipAdd]
| eval fillOutTime=(submitTime-retrieveTime)/60
```

But this only results in a table with IP Addresses and submit times. I've also tried adding the following at the end:

```
| where fillOutTime>0
```

But in this form the form is often retrieved one more time after submitting, so this doesn't work for this particular form. Is there a way to use the submit time (the last retrieval time BEFORE submitting the form) in the search as a latest time in the search for retrieval time, or should I use a different command?

Answer (score 0):

The subsearch of a `join` is independent of the main search and all other subsearches so there is no way for the subsearch to use anything from elsewhere in the query.

The `join` command should be avoided because it performs poorly.

To solve the problem, fetch the time the form was submitted (should be a POST or PUT operation) and subtract the time the form was retrieved (a GET).

````
index=sys POST form
| rex "(?<ipAdd>.*), \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}, \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}" 
| stats latest(_time) as submitTime by ipAdd
| append 
        [search index=sys GET form
    | rex "(?<ipAdd>.*), \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}, \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}"
    | stats latest(_time) as retrieveTime by ipAdd]
``` Merge the appended results with the results of the main search ```
| stats values(*) as * by idAdd
| eval fillOutTime=(submitTime-retrieveTime)/60
````